# Prevent removing markers from layer when the map is refreshed

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, leaflet, layer

I'm begginer, so I have complicated project. 
I have a map that refreshes every 10 seconds, and button that generate coordinates, time, and event(marker) for each id. 
When I press that button first time, new data is generated for odd id's, when I press it second time, its generated for even id's.

Ajax:

```
function callAjax() {
        console.log('ajax');
        $.ajax({
            url: '/device_new',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                var coordinates = data;

                markerLayer.clearLayers();

                for (var i = 0; i < coordinates.length; i++) {
                    var icon = getMarkerType(coordinates[i].event);
                    if (coordinates[i].x && coordinates[i].y) {

                        marker = L.marker([coordinates[i].x, coordinates[i].y], {
                                icon: icon
                            })

                            .bindPopup("Device ID: " + coordinates[i].deviceId + '<br>' + "Time: " + coordinates[i].datetime);

                        marker.addTo(markerLayer).addTo(map);
                    }
                }
                map.fitBounds(markerLayer.getBounds(), { padding: [50, 50] });
            },
        });
        setTimeout(callAjax, 10000);
    }
```

Update script:

```
function updatedev() {
        $.ajax({
            //the route pointing to the post function
            url: '/device/update/',
            data: {
                id: updateDeviceNew
            },
            type: 'GET',
            // remind that 'data' is the response of the AjaxController
            success: function(data) {
                updateDeviceNew++;
            },
        });
    }
```

Controller:

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    $value =$request->id;

    $number=Device_new::get()->count();


    //while i < broj zapisa u tabeli $device_new = Device_new::where('deviceId',1)->update(['x' => $x, 'y' => $y, 'datetime' => $datetime]); prvi put za neparne drugi put za poarne itd
    if($value%2!=0)
    $i=1;
    else
    $i=2; 
    for ($i; $i<=$broj; $i+=2){
        $x = rand(44450000, 45000000) / 1000000;
        $y = rand(16400000, 17900000) / 1000000;
        $event=rand(1,4);
        $datetime = new Carbon('now','Europe/Belgrade');


        $device_new = Device_new::where('deviceId',$i)->update(['x' => $x, 'y' => $y, 'datetime' => $datetime, 'event' => $event]);
    }
    return $number;
}
```

As you can see in callAjax(), there is command `markerLayer.clearLayers();` that remove layer with markers, and in the end of loop create layer again. That is a problem for me, because it refresh map and write new and old markers again.

Can I somehow prevent to rewrite unchanged markers?

Answer (score 1):

You're adding each new layer to both the `markerLayer` and the map. Clearing the layers from the `markerLayer` doesn't clear them from the map. Suggest you don't add them to the map, so change

```
marker.addTo(markerLayer).addTo(map);
```

to

```
marker.addTo(markerLayer);
```

Having added `markerLayer` to the map once.

Comment: In loadMap() i have 'markerLayer = L.featureGroup().addTo(map);', but I dont think that this i solution for my problem. 
Is it possible to rewrite only updated markers?